# Android widget with custom font

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I am trying to create a simple android widget that shows and I want to use custom font in my application, can anyone help me?

this my code :

```
public class ExampleAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ExampleWidget";
    private static final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

    /**
     * Custom Intent name that is used by the AlarmManager to tell us to update
     * the clock once per second.
     */
    public static String CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE = "com.eightbitcloud.example.widget.8BITCLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        if (CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Clock update");
            // Get the widget manager and ids for this widget provider, then
            // call the shared
            // clock update method.
            ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(
                    context.getPackageName(), getClass().getName());
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager
                    .getInstance(context);
            int ids[] = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);
            for (int appWidgetID : ids) {
                updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetID);

            }
        }
    }

    private PendingIntent createClockTickIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        return pendingIntent;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        super.onDisabled(context);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Widget Provider disabled. Turning off timer");
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(createClockTickIntent(context));
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        super.onEnabled(context);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,
                "Widget Provider enabled.  Starting timer to update widget every second");
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                1000, createClockTickIntent(context));
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Updating Example Widgets.");

        // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this
        // provider
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetExampleActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    intent, 0);

            // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
            // to the button
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget1);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);
            // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app
            // widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

            // Update The clock label using a shared method
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    public static void updateAppWidget(Context context,
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
        String currentTime = df.format(new Date());

        RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget1);
        updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget1label, currentTime);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, updateViews);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your title.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535164/how-to-change-the-font-in-android-widgets-to-user-defined-fonts-in-assets-fold) SO question might help.